# Конвертация .sql в .db

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Нужно конвертировать файл .sql в .db.

Comment: Нажмите F2 и смените расширение

Comment: psql: `\i file.sql`

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Пожалуйста, перенесите свой комментарий в ответы, чтобы я мог отметить его решением

Comment: @Sterri Ну это ж postgresql, а у вас наверно sqlite3 ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Подумайте логически: если я попросил перенести, значит это сработало, значит я всё же использовал postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "\i file.sql"
```

Answer (score 2):

Однозначного ответа вы не получите поскольку. sql файлы это обычно файлы скриптов они в текстовом формате. db файлы данных. И я не вижу взаимосвязи такой чтоб любой файл скриптов можно преобразовать в файл данных. Да возможны случаи когда результатом работы файла скриптов получится база данных, но это вовсе не конвертация